# Distancematrix with Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel

I'm quite new to programming things in Java, especially doing it to create a Excel file. But maybe someone could help me with this problem.

I currently created via Apache Poi and Eclipse a spreadsheet in Excel. In there I got 3 columns and 40 Rows. These are filled with coordinates ( x and y-coordinates) and their names (in my case, 1 - 40). Now that I finally got these random numbers, I want to create a distance matrix (with euclidean distance) between those points. 
For Example I want to have it look like:

1  2  3
1  0  1  2
2  1  0  4
3  2  4  0

I'm not sure how to get this created random numbers and to calculate with them. As well as I'm not sure how to implement the formular for the euclidean distance. It would be awesome if someone could help me! Thanks in advance!

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import java.util.Random;

public class poiexample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        XSSFWorkbook Datei = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (new File ("Dateien.xlsx"));




        for(int  i=0;i<101;i++)
        {   XSSFSheet Blatt = Datei.createSheet("Tabelle" + i);
            XSSFRow row1 = Blatt.createRow(0);
            row1.createCell(2).setCellValue("x");
            row1.createCell(3).setCellValue("y");

            for(int j=0; j<25; j++) {
            XSSFRow row = Blatt.createRow(j+1);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("P"+j);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(j+1);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(Math.round(Math.random()*10));
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(Math.round(Math.random()*10));

        }
            for(int j=25; j<40; j++) {
                XSSFRow row = Blatt.createRow(j+1);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("D");
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(j+1);
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(Math.round(Math.random()*10));
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(Math.round(Math.random()*10));

            }


        } 


    try {



        Datei.write(out);
        out.close();

    }
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
    System.out.println("Excel file created");


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I See you are generating the co-ordinates and writing into excel sheet. Then you want to create the euclidean  matrix.

I suggest, first you have these co-ordinates in a 2D array and arrive at the algorithm to calculate the euclidean distance matrix. Then it is just a matter of writing all the co-ordinates and the distance matrix into excel file.

If you have the co-ordinates already in an excel, just read the excel and populate the 2D array and then call your routine to calculate and generate the euclidean  matrix

Of course there may be better solutions, this what I can think of right now.